# How to write text file via emulator?

Tags: android

Yesterday i post this question and some one replied me by peace of codes but the problem is permission denied. i do not know why happen this error because i have allowed permission in my manifest.xml. below is peace of code.

This is java code

```
public void WriteText() {
   EditText txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtwrite);

   try {
        BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/"+"File.txt"));
        fos.write(txt.getText().toString().trim());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

This is manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please any one help me i was so Straggled about it.

Comment: your error message + google = 1 zillion answers.

Comment: Print exception to logcat: e.printStackTrace() and paste logcat. And version of android.

Comment: It seems the code is right. Are trying this on real device? Maybe sdcard is not inserted in emulator?

Comment: And after Toast.makeText you forgot about show()

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help now i know how to write and read my problem was from android version.